# fast reciprocal (1/x)

Tags: c++

I was seeing alot of machine learning applications calculate fitness via `1.0 / x`. Division in computers is slow so I came up with a version that is about ~36% fast on my architecture (`-march=x86-64`).

```cpp
#include <cmath>    //std::exp2, std::log
#include <numbers>  //std::numbers::log2e
#include <stdlib.h> //rand, srand
#include <iostream> //std::cout

float reciprical( float y )
{
    //e^-ln(y)
    //std::pow( log10e,  -std::log(y) )                   //~19s
    return std::exp2(std::numbers::log2e * -std::log(y)); //~17s
}

float reciprical2( float y )
{
    return 1/y;                                           //~23s
}

int main(){
    srand(1);
    for(int i=0; i < 10000000000; ++i) std::cout << reciprical(rand());
}
```

I got inspiration from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114588

Comment: It is very unlikely that applying two transcedental functions is faster than a single division. The runtime is dominated by the output to `std::cout`. Also, why use `std::exp2(std::numbers::log2e * ...)` when you can just use `std::exp(...)`?

Comment: Side note but I noticed that there's two different spellings of reciprocal/reciprical which could be confusing

Comment: I also recommend you use a benchmarking library, like https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/README.md, and also look at the generated assembly code with a tool like https://godbolt.org/.

Comment: (1 all I can say is try it on your machine and see if it's faster and also (2 I didn't think about `std::exp(std::numbers::log10e *  -std::log(y));`

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: You claim this is to accelerate an AI application. Have you actually tried it there?

Comment: This feels a bit like saying that your merge sort implementation was a bit slow so you optimized it by replacing it with bubble sort.

Comment: Micro-review - spelling is __reciprocal__.  Sounds trivial, but misspellings can make it hard to find functions you _know_ exist in your code-base!

Answer (score 5):

Including IO in a benchmark is no good. I tried some [different benchmarks on quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/onmsxwkyLVdK7PUs3v4rrk5xqtc) and the results were different: the versions with Expensive Functions (`log`, `exp`, etc) were much slower. Looking at the assembly, there was no "cheating" such as vectorizing the benchmark loop with the plain division - on the other hand, maybe that wouldn't be cheating, but a realistic representation of how it may work out in real situations. So you could even say that the division is likely to be *better than this result shows* in many (but not all) situations.

Such results do depend on the specific micro-architecture though. As a specific example, `divss` on Intel Haswell and before had less than half the throughput than on Intel Broadwell and later. `log` and `exp` can be implemented without division, so the *relative cost* will be different on different processors. That may also explain part of the differences we observed, but that does not take away that benchmarks should not include significant sources of overhead that aren't the subject of the benchmark.

On your architecture (and many others) there is a special hardware-accelerated approximate reciprocal. Indeed on some architectures, division is not a primitive at all and can only be implemented in terms of such an approximate reciprocal ([that's tricky](https://projects.ncsu.edu/wcae//ISCA2004/submissions/cornea.pdf)). For x86, you can write this, for a quite accurate but not perfect reciprocal:

```
float reciprocal(float y)
{
    float r = _mm_cvtss_f32(_mm_rcp_ss(_mm_set_ss(y)));
    r = r * (2 - r * y);
    return r;
}
```

The Newton-Raphson step is optional if you can accept a reduced precision, with a relative error of up to \$1.5 \cdot 2^{-12}\$.

Note than all the benchmarks that I linked before are for *throughput*, if you're in a situation where *latency* is important, an approximate reciprocal followed by a Newton-Raphson step [is not actually good](https://quick-bench.com/q/4H_VK95_Wc7KoM3UIxijFdjVjXA). Pentium4 may have been an exception to that, since it had a much slower division, but Pentium4 is not very relevant today.

Comment: if using intrinsiscs you can use `_mm_rcp_ss(__m128 a)` (SSE)

Comment: @AlexAngel yes that's what I used above, unfortunately it's not as simple as just throwing it in there, since the function signature is inconvenient

Comment: Ya, I commented that before I looked at your benchmark/code

Comment: @harold, in your benchmark (1st link) there are two data type conversions in reciprocal2 function which, by quick-bench,  takes ~27% of the execution time. Constant 1.44269504089 type is double so make it float... . Maybe not much speed up though ... .

Comment: @JuhaP the original code has that feature, `std::numbers::log2e` is a `double` after all. I now [tested it with a float](https://quick-bench.com/q/JAdsDTC8d6aERWzihYLM9pfoPaI) and that didn't help (I agree that it *could* have, though). Btw I recommend interpreting line-based timing with several grains of salt, they tend to suffer from [skid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369347/reliability-of-xcode-instruments-disassembly-time-profiling#comment84227298_48369347) and other imperfections

Answer (score 1):

The [rcpss](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcpss) assembly instruction computes an approximate reciprocal with |Relative Error| ≤ 1.5 ∗ 2^−12.

You can enable it on a compiler with the `-mrecip` flag (you might also need `-ffast-math`).

The instrinsic is `_mm_rcp_ss`.

Comment: Is this portable?

Comment: @pacmaninbw: In what way? Your architecture needs the instruction, so it's not portable in that sense. But it might still work on >80% of all computers or something like that.

Comment: Do all compilers have that flag?  Alex has said which platform is targeted, but not which compiler (though that `-march=x86-64` option probably implies a smaller set of compilers than we'd otherwise have to assume).